# bucket size in bucket sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to write code for bucket sort, but am confused in bucket size of each bucket. My code is below.
input array: {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7,10,22,4,16,1,26};

I am passing bucket size of each bucket >3 then I dont get the output in sorted order. It gives perfect ans for bucket size 1 and 2

```
public void bucsort(int[] arr,int bucketSize){

        if(arr.length==0) return;

        int max=arr[0];
        int min=arr[0];

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]<min)
            {
                min=arr[i];
            }
            else
                max=arr[i];
        }
        int bucketCount= (max - min) / bucketSize + 1;
         List<List<Integer>> buckets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(bucketCount);
        // int divider= (max+1)/bucketCount;

         for (int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++) {
                buckets.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            }
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                buckets.get((arr[i]-min) / bucketSize).add(arr[i]);
            }
         int currentIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
                Integer[] bucketArray = new Integer[buckets.get(i).size()];
                bucketArray = buckets.get(i).toArray(bucketArray);
                InsertionSort(bucketArray);
                for (int j = 0; j < bucketArray.length; j++) {
                    arr[currentIndex++] = bucketArray[j];
                }
            }       
    }
```

Is there any relation between no. of buckets and its size ?

I edited my method for max-min function and also debugged the program. There seems to be some mistake in my insertion sort

the code is:

```
public void InsertionSort(Integer[] arr){


        for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
            int value=arr[i];
            int hole=i;

            while(hole>0 && arr[hole-1]>value){

                arr[hole]=arr[hole-1];

                hole--;
            }

            arr[hole-1]=value;
        }
    }
```

main func

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7,10,22,4,16,1,26};

        BucketSort ob = new BucketSort();
        ob.bucsort(arr, 5);
        printArray(arr);
    }
    static void printArray(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

My output for bucket size 5 : 5 1 4 6 7 10 12 11 13 16 22 26 
for size 3: 1 5 4 6 7 12 10 11 13 16 22 26 
for size 2: 1 4 5 6 7 10 12 11 13 16 22 26

Comment: Hint: learn to use a debugger and/or how to use trace statements within your code in order to **observe** what it is doing. You got your code in front of you; so the only thing required to understand what it is doing ... is some curiosity on your end (I am telling you that because one learns programming from hunting down bugs; not by delegating that task to other people). And of course, when you go to ask ask; include all relevant code, not just half of it!

Comment: Could there be a bug in your `InsertionSort` method? We can help you better if you post complete code and complete output with different bucket sizes in your question (say, size 2 and size 4).

Comment: It’s an aside, I believe your way of finding the max happens to work for your input example, but will fail for other inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `InsertionSort` method you do

```
        int value=arr[i];
        int hole=i;

        while(hole>0 && arr[hole]>value){
```

At this point `arr[hole]` will always equal `value`, so you never get into the `while` loop. So nothing gets sorted. For small bucket sizes, you may be lucky that it doesn’t matter. For bucket size 1, it certainly doesn’t. Even for bucket size 2 you have a single error in the sorting. I get:

```
1 4 5 6 7 10 12 11 13 16 22 26
```

12 comes before 11 because those two numbers end up in the same bucket and don’t get sorted.

I took this from your comment: `while (hole > 0 && arr[hole - 1] > value) {`. On your request, now the method looks like this:

```
public void insertionSort(Integer[] arr) { // renamed to small i since it’s a method

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int value = arr[i];
        int hole = i;

        while (hole > 0 && arr[hole - 1] > value) {

            arr[hole] = arr[hole - 1];

            hole--;
        }

        arr[hole] = value;
    }
}
```

Now I get correct sorting with all bucket sizes from 1 to 19. If you still have a problem, there must be something we are not doing the same way.

It’s an aside, but as has been mentioned a couple of times, there is a bug in your code for finding `max`. I tried this input:

```
    int arr[] = { 3, 10, 4 };
```

I get a `max`of 4 (expected: 10) and then a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1` at this line:

```
            buckets.get((arr[i]-min) / bucketSize).add(arr[i]);
```

Comment: I have used while(hole>0 && arr[hole-1]>value)

Comment: Sounds like an improvement. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I even tried using hole-i-1 and made changes accordingly in other parts of code...but it also does not work

Comment: I have edited the max function already in my IDE..just not edited it in my main question..I am getting `1 4 6 6 7 10 11 11 13 16 22 26`   when I use hole=i-1.Can you please post your whole insertion sort code.It will be a great help

Comment: ok I got it.I was replacing  arr[hole] = value; as `arr[hole-1]=value` so it was not getting sorted .Now its working properly. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Finding max-min is wrong...(you have some logical error)

```
int minValue = array[0];
        int maxValue = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = array[i];
            } else if (array[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = array[i];
            }
        }
```

On your code:

```
     1 4 3 
min  1 1 1
max  1 4 3
```

This will be the correct implemenation

```
for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                  tmp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                  arr[j - 1] = tmp;
                  j--;
            }
}
```

I will debug your code when I get time..

Comment: What you write is correct, but it is hardly an answer to the question.

Comment: @OleV.V.: There is no otherway we or anybody can comment on his/her implemenation. He/she should post the Insertion sort code also and with insertion sort correctly written this code works.

Comment: @coderredoc: I made the changes you told and debugged the program. There seems mistake in my insertion sort but I am not able to find what as my logic seems to be correct

Comment: @Ankita.: lemme check

Comment: Its working now.I was not replacing the final hole element with the value. thank you for pointing out my max function mistake